# Executing dependent tasks in java

Tags: java, concurrency, dependencies, scheduled-tasks

I need to find a way to execute mutually dependent tasks.

- First task has to download a zip file from remote server.
- Second tasks goal is to unzip the file downloaded by the first task.
- Third task has to process files extracted from zip.

so, third is dependent on second and second on first task.
Naturally if one of the tasks fails, others shouldn't be executed. Since the first task downloads files from remote server, there should be a mechanism for restarting the task is server is not available. 
Tasks have to be executed daily.

Any suggestions, patterns or java API?

Regards!

Comment: They are all depending on eachother, why devide them?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do not want to devide them into tasks, just do like this:

```
process(unzip(download(uri)));
```

Comment: yes, this could be a single task with 3 methods executed one after another. I was concerned with repeating the download job if server was unavailable.

Comment: Then rename `download` to `downloadWithRetries` and let that method call `download` a couple of times...

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on external requirements. Is there any user involvement? Monitoring? Alerting?...

The simplest would obviously be just methods that check if the previous has done what it should.

1. `download()` downloads file to specified place.
2. `unzip()` extracts the file to a specified place if the downloaded file is in place.
3. `process()` processes the data if it has been extracted.

A more "formal" way of doing it would be to use a workflow engine. Depending on requirements, you can get some that do everything from fancy UIs, to some that follow formal standardised .XML-definitions of the workflow - and any in between.

http://java-source.net/open-source/workflow-engines

Comment: There is no user involvement but it would be useful to alert if task A could not download the zip file.

Comment: So you need to decide if it's simple enough to do it all programatically, or if it warrants the use of some workflow engine. Generally I resist using frameworks until there's enough gain by having one. Simple independent code is easier to maintain.

Comment: I agree. But I thought of using some of the java concurrency api.

Comment: So are you going to have several of these tasks execute in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

Create one public method to execute the full chain and private methods for the tasks:

```
public void doIt() {
  if (download() == false) {
     // download failed
  } else if (unzip() == false) {
     // unzip failed;
  } else (process() == false)
     // processing failed
  }
}

private boolean download() {/* ... */}
private boolean unzip() {/* ... */}
private boolean process() {/* ... */}
```

So you have an API that gurantees that all steps are executed in the correct sequence and that a step is only executed if certain conditions are met (the above example just illustrates this pattern)

Answer (score 0):

For daily execution you can use the [Quartz Framework](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/).

As the tasks are depending on each other I would recommend to evaluate the error codes or exceptions the tasks are returning. Then just continue if the previous task was successful.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to perform these tasks is to; call each task in order, and throw an exception when you have a failure which prevents the following tasks being performed.  Something like

```
try {
  download();
  unzip();
  process();
} catch(Exception failed) {
  failed.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: this is the simplest way of doing this, implement all three methods ant put them in the single task. It could be done with java.util.timer

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are interested in is some kind of transaction definition.
I.e.
- Define `TaskA` (e.g. download)
- Define `TaskB` (e.g. unzip)
- Define `TaskC` (e.g. process)
Assuming that you intention is to have tasks working independent as well, e.g. only download a file (not execute also TaskB, TaskC) you should define `Transaction1` composed of `TaskA,TaskB,TaskC` or `Transaction2` composed of only `TaskA`.
The semantics e.g. concerning **Transaction1** that TaskA,TaskB and TaskC should be executed sequentially and all or none could be captured in your transaction definitions.
The definitions can be in xml configuration files and you can use a framework e.g. Quartz for scheduling.
A higher construct shall check for the transactions and execute them as defined.

Answer (score 0):

Dependent tasks execution made easy with [Dexecutor](https://github.com/dexecutor/dexecutor-core/wiki)

Disclaimer : I am the owner of the library

Basically you need the following pattern

[image]

Use Dexecutor.addDependency method

```
 DefaultDexecutor<Integer, Integer> executor = newTaskExecutor();
//Building
executor.addDependency(1, 2);
executor.addDependency(2, 3);
executor.addDependency(3, 4);
executor.addDependency(4, 5);
//Execution
executor.execute(ExecutionConfig.TERMINATING);
```